# Are file system operations such as rename/unlink cached?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

As we know that file writings are cache by Linux OS and only get commited to disk when the OS has to do so or fsync() is called.

But, 
Are file system operations such as rename/unlink cached? And does a successful return from rename/unlink ensure that the operation is commited to disk and will survive even OS crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this kind of stuff was instantly written out the performance would be beyond terrible.

There are various approaches: log-structured filesystems, soft-updates, journaling and probably more.

I suggest you read http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf

Comment: But if the OS crashes, eg. because of power loss, before those operations were written to disk. The operation will be lost. What's worse, if those operations are written in a disordered way, we will get a none constant state after crashes and restarts.

Comment: Is there a way to force those operations to be written to disk?

Comment: I see I did not explicitly state: rename/whatever *does not* guarantee consistency, you have to fsync the dir fd. Other than that, you may have partially performed operations which the fs will be able to complete or discard. I gave you names of 3 general approaches to this.